# Animating fixed navigation while scrolling - bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

i'm currently working on a website, which should have a similar functionality like this one: http://nzopera.com/2013/the-flying-dutchman

You can see the effect i'm talking about, if you scroll down on the page above. 
1. ) The top and bottom padding of the header shrinks and after that you literally "scroll" the header out of your viewport. 
2.) If you keep scrolling down a bit (to the content area) and then scroll up again, the navigation becomes visible.

I haven't implemented the second effect yet, because i want to solve a problem with the first one before. I've created a quick fiddle with my current status: http://jsfiddle.net/FN8D/1/embedded/result/
The HTML markup is pretty simple:

```
<header><!- HEADER CONTENT / NAVIGATION -></header>
<div><!- MAIN CONTENT / NAVIGATION -></div>
```

I'm not sure if i have to put my JS Code in here, because it is pretty long. If i do have to, please tell me. You can have a look at the JS in the fiddle link though. What the JS does, is checking the scroll direction and calling the function, which calculates the CSS values (based on the current scroll positon). The function has several parameters:

```
startValue : Initial CSS value
endValue : The CSS value to animate to
distance : After which distance scrolled (in px) should the "animation" be over?
initScroll : When (in px) should the "animation" start?
```

Currently the first effect (see above) mostly works, but when you compare it to the one in the link above it has some issues:
1.) All the values in my code are hard coded. Do you have any ideas how to do it different / better? E.g. the values for the padding are hardcoded in JS. So if i change the "padding" in the CSS file, i'll have to change it in the JS file as well. Or the "padding-top"-value on the "body" is hard-coded, but it is dependent on the initial height of the header. So is the "top"-value of the header (to show or hide the header), which is dependent on the height of the header (without the initial large padding).
– To solve at least some of these hard coded values i thought of using data-attributes (at least start and end value) in the HTML, so at least i don't have to change anything in the JS. Do you think this could work? Though i don't have a solution for the "top"-value to show and hide the header. It somehow has to be dependent on the height (after the padding shrinks) of the header. And i don't have a solution for all the other remaining hard-coded values yet.

2.) You may have noticed a small white gap, when you scroll back to the top after the scrolled down. For me this is the most important issue right now, because i really don't know how to fix it at all. Sometimes it also happens that the white gap (screenshot attached[image: Small Gap while scrolling back to the top]) is pretty big, because the "animation" doesn't finish properly. In comparision to nzopera.com my code seems pretty slow (to me) and the animation is not as smooth. I think that is why the small white gap appears. I could of course change the background to black (same color as header) to "remove" the white gap, but this won't work, because the content background-color should be white and there won't be a large header image on every page. There needs to be a proper solution to fix that, nzopera.com does it as well somehow. Any help would be really appreciated.

So far that's all. I properly have more questions as soon as i start implementing the second effect ;) Thanks in advance. Just for your information: As you might see in my code, i'm not good in JS at all. If you have any other suggestion to improve anything, please tell me... still learning :)

Comment: have you thought of using SMINT for this? it could save you some time: http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buddy, i reworked your jquery function, look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FN8Dc/4/.
Now this should work on all dimensions you set in the css, so you dont need to change anything in the js file.

Now allow me to explain my code:

CSS code:

1. i deleted the padding top from body that you used to align the image
   with the header.
2. i set the `z-index` of `.element` to 2 so that `.element` is visible above all items, you can set it to 999 in the future according to your needs.
3. i added `position: relative` to `.container` because we need it to align the element using jquery.

Now for the jquery code:

1. `var $element_outer_height = $(".element").outerHeight(),` will give use the height of `.element` + the padding values.
2. `$element_padding = ($element_outer_height - $(".element").height()) / 2;` will give us the value of `padding-top` initially used in `.element`, this value will be used below.
3. we use this value first to align the container directly below the element: `$(".container").css({ top: $element_outer_height});`.
4. On window scroll, we do a test:

   - if the scrolled value is below the outer height of `.element`, we must reduce the padding of `.element` and decrease the `top` value of `.container`so that `.container` still be good aligned with `.element`.
   - if the scrolled value reaches the outer height of `.element`, we must here set the `top` value of `.element` top minus the height of it and the `padding` to `0`, thus: `$(".element").css({top: -1 * $(".element").height(), padding: 0});`.

Hope this will help, because it took a lot of work :D

Comment: Big thanks for your effort, really appreciate. Your code solves some problems for my first question and how to get rid of hard coded values. If i look at the fiddle it doesn't look quite right to me. You got rid of the small white gap, but therefore the header overlaps the content area. I think you don't need to recalculate the "top"-value of the content alongside the header.outerHeight(). Nzopera.com does have a fixed "padding-top" for the body as well. And for me the "animation" of the header is a little bit strange. It shrinks the padding to 0 and then suddenly it disappears :)

Comment: first, i didint understand "the header overlaps the content area" if you can explain it to me :) second, i didint look at the code of nzopera.com, i just did take a look at the effect, so if you want the same way of solving the problem i can do it i think. and the last thing about the animation, i will give you a modified fiddle, i which the the padding shrink to a value you decide it then it will disapear, i think this is the right way for the animation :)

Comment: so this is what i did to fix the animation, take l look at this fidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/FN8Dc/8. the value of "$desired_value" is the key to the animation, you just change it and see the result :)

Comment: Thanks once again, the animation looks a lot better to me now. To demonstrate, what i mean with overlap, i made a screenshot. The image is underneath the header and doesn't align properly: http://i.imgur.com/fVFCLD3.jpg . I updated your fiddle with a fixed padding top on the body and some adjustments in the javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/FN8Dc/9/embedded/result/
Now it doesn't "overlap" anymore, but padding now doesn't shrink to the "desired-value" anymore.

Comment: Anyways, how would you solve the second effect with your code? When you scroll down on nzopera.com quite a bit to the content or even more  and then scroll up a bit, the header "appears" again, even if you are not at the very top. First you'll have to call a function as soon as you change the scroll direction from "down" to "up". This i already managed to do in my first fiddle. But then you'll have to recalculate the "top"-value for the header again somehow... Properly you know a way.

Comment: So after a hard work, this is the what i did: http://jsfiddle.net/FN8Dc/12/embedded/result/.
if this work for you tell me to explain it :D

Comment: Actually this works really well. There are some little bugs with the second effect, but i need to have a look at your code, probably i can fix it myself: Sometimes the header "top"-position while scrolling up and down jumps a bit, not sure why it does that, but i haven't checked your code yet in detail. The first effect works really well though. I first need to have a look at the JS to understand how you achieved that. Thank you very much for your effort ! :)

Comment: that's great...glad i could help...if you need anything with the code tell me and i will explain it :) good luck